# Dominoes - Competition

Tags: algorithm, search, tree

http://ecoocs.org/contests/ecoo_2007.pdf

I'm studying for the upcoming ecoo regionals for my area and I'm stumped on this one question. I really have no idea where to start.

It is in the "regional" "west and central" section "problem 3 - domino chains".

I keep going over the problem manually and I keep thinking of breadth first search or depth first search, but the dominoes having two sides is seriously throwing my thinking off.
Does anyone have any advice, or maybe some resources that might set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this problem calls for a recursive backtracking approach. Keep a 7 by 7 symmetric matrix showing which numbers are attached to which. For example, given tiles `00 12 63 51` you would have the following matrix:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
  -------------
0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1|0 0 1 0 0 1 0
2|1 0 0 0 0 0 0
3|0 0 0 0 0 0 1
4|0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5|0 1 0 0 0 0 0
6|0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

When you use up a tile by placing it in a potential chain, delete it from the matrix, and put it back in the matrix after you unplace the tile by backtracking.  For example, if the chain currecntly contains `51 12`, the matrix looks like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
  -------------
0|1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1|0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2|0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3|0 0 0 0 0 0 1
4|0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5|0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6|0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Given that the chain currecntly ends in 2, you would look along row 2 for any numbers that can connect to. Not finding any, you would mark down `51 12` as a potential longest chain, and then backtrack to the state where the chain contained only `51`.

Maintain a set of all the longest chains you have found, and check a new chain for the existence of itself or its reverse in the set before inserting it.

If you find a longer chain, start a new set. Once you have exhaustively searched through all the possible chains, the size of your set should be the number of variations that are of the longest length.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, when working out these sorts of problems, a great way to solve them is to do them in one case (taking into account that you will increase complexity later) and then increase the complexity.  That way you aren't overwhelmed by the complexity and the almost endless "whatifs" that a problem like this can cause.

Also, on the programming competitions I've participated in, 60-70% of the credit was awarded for a solution that got the basic problem correct, and then final percentages were if you handled certain cases correctly.  The case that sticks in my mind specifically is we had a mapping problem with a variation of the travelling salesman and if they supplied a graph with a loop, did my solution loop endlessly or did it do something about it.

Thus, with this approach, what I would do is try to solve the problem as directly as possible: take the input as stated by the documentation and just generate the longest chain with the pieces you have.  Then increment the complexity by allowing pieces to be rotated etc.

While this is a personal approach to the problem, it has served me well in the past.  I hope it serves you well also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem, so you can solve it using dynamic programming techniques.

So, if we have these pieces:

```
45 36 46 56
```

What is **the longest chain that can be made from 4 bones**?
Obviously, **the longest chain that can be made from 3 bones** and 1 more bone.

What is **the longest chain that can be made from 3 bones**?
Obviously, **the longest chain that can be made from 2 bones** and 1 more bone.

What is **the longest chain that can be made from 2 bones**?
Obviously, **the longest chain that can be made from 1 bone** and 1 more bone.

What is **the longest chain that can be made from 1 bone**?
Obviously, 1 bone is the longest possible chain.

I think you see by the pattern here, we need to use recursion.

So if we have:

```
45 36 46 56
```

Suppose we have a function `longest_chain(set_of_pieces)`. Then we need to check:

```
longest_chain({36 46 56}) (+ 1 if we can append 45 or 54 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({45 46 56}) (+ 1 if we can append 36 or 63 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({45 36 56}) (+ 1 if we can append 46 or 64 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({45 36 46}) (+ 1 if we can append 56 or 65 else discard this chain)
```

what is `longest_chain({36 46 56})`?

```
longest_chain({46 56}) (+ 1 if we can append 36 or 63 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({36 56}) (+ 1 if we can append 46 or 64 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({36 46}) (+ 1 if we can append 56 or 65 else discard this chain)
```

what is `longest_chain({46 56})`?

```
longest_chain({46}) (+ 1 if we can append 56 or 65 else discard this chain)
longest_chain({56}) (+ 1 if we can append 46 or 64 else discard this chain)
```

what is `longest_chain({46})`? Two possibilities: `{46} {64}`
Can we append 56 or 65 to any of these? Yes, we can make this chain `{46, 65}` and we discard `{64}`.
Do the same with `longest_chain({56})` and we get: `{56, 64}`.

Therefore, we now know that `longest_chain({46 56})` are `{46, 65}, {56, 64}`

Continue doing this until you get all answers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This needs to count variations.

Comment: @Null Set: no need, with a few tricks, all the variations will be handled automatically.

Comment: Reversed chains are considered identical and not counted as variations.

Comment: @Null Set: good point, but it is trivial to modify the approach so reversed chains are considered identical

Comment: This will stack overflow I'm thinking.  there are a max possible 60 dominoes.  59! is a big number to be recursing on.

Comment: @Thebigcheeze: Using `28` bone domino, the maximum stack depth is `28` (not `28!`), at any point in time. I'm not sure I get why you think this will stack overflow.

Comment: @Thebigcheeze Actually you're guaranteed to be given no more than 12 tiles to work with.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the problem definition, I thought it said it gave you 5 sets, each of which was a maximum of 12 tiles, and you should find the longest link across the sets.  If, instead, you are to find the longest link for each set, and then the longest link of those links, then yes, the number would be much smaller than previously stated.  I thought it would be of a factorial degree because if you wanted to check `longest_chain({12, 34, 56, 78})` you would remove `78` and check `{12, 34, 56}` and `{12, 34, 65}` and `{12, 43, 56}` etc.  I see this is not 12! but instead 2^12.

Comment: This solution will not consider all possible chains if backtracking is required `{12, 23, 31, 24, 24}`. Solving a similar problem I resorted to brute force permutations using Heap's algorithm to probe every possible chain. There's likely a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd start.

Label the `n` dominoes `D1..Dn`.

Let `Cm` be the set of chains formed using the subset of domines `D1..Dm` (and `C0 = {}`).

`Cm+1` is formed by trying to insert Dm+1 into all possible places in chains in `Cm`, plus using `Dm+1` where possible to concatenate pairs of disjoint chains from `Cm`, plus the singleton chain consisting of `Dm+1` by itself.

You can probably do some optimisation (e.g., ordering the dominoes), but I'd be inclined to just try this as is before getting too clever.